how to display images kept in a folder one by one using index.html
html file like this:
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Department Events">
</head>
<title> Recent and Ongoing Events in the Department of Physics </title>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<center>
<img style="width: 985px; height: 408px;" src="physics-1.jpg">
<h1 style="color:blue;">Department of Physics - Events and Activities</h1>
<hr>
</body>
</html>

Here I display image physics-1.jpg.  But I want to display all images one by one from a folder photo so that each image is shown for 10 seconds and then changes to next images and ultimately back to first image and so on...
Could you please guide me what changes are needed in index.html page?
Thanks
a simple working example html code would be very helpful.

There are a ton of libraries that does this. Just search for 'image slider'. You can also make it yourself if you want to: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Please don't use StackOverflow as a code delivery service. Do research on your own for a library that can help here or implement something on your own and we can certainly help debug. Please see: Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?

What you are trying to achieve is a typical slider, where images changes after some amount of time passed. You cannot create a slider just with HTML, you need to know about CSS or JavaScript to change the images dynamically.

I am not  much into CSS or Java , so any simple example code would be helpful

@SushilChauhan, You can use Chat GPT for that. search Chat GPT and ask it to create whatever you want. You can learn from it as well.

This is slider just created with HTML and CSS, Check this out bro.
Link:  https://codepen.io/saran_3012/pen/PogrQZZ
HTML
<div id="slider-container">
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://e0.pxfuel.com/wallpapers/316/193/desktop-wallpaper-javascript.jpg" alt="image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/73/e9/b073e9150cc603e3a5b757be38fc771b.jpg" alt="image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://blog.appsignal.com/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2Fblog%2F2022-12%2Ftop-5-nodejs-posts-in-2022.png&w=1920&q=50" alt="image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:805/1*7fe7SkSNP6Y8PvTRm4Jl6Q.png" alt="image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://webimages.mongodb.com/_com_assets/cms/kuzt9r42or1fxvlq2-Meta_Generic.png" alt="image"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#slider-container{
  margin: auto;
  height: 380px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  animation: slider 10s infinite;
}

.card{
  border: 2px solid white;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@keyframes slider{
  0%, 100%{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  20%{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  40%{
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
  60%{
    transform: translateX(-300%);
  }
  80%{
    transform: translateX(-400%);
  }
}

If you are a beginner, you can try learning CSS and JavaScript.
It can enhance your web.
And try to avoid inline styles (Do not embed the styles in HTML). It makes the debugging harder.

thanks bro will read more about CSS and JavaS. Thanks again.

Plain HTML does not support such dynamic abilities. For that you need to use other mechanisms such as Javascript client-side code, something like :


<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="Department Events">
        <script>
            var folder = 'https://i.imgur.com/' // set where your images are stored in server
            var images = ['MrqyDDY.jpeg', 'YnSn3Fj.jpeg', 's3xpPGP.png'] // list of image files
            var loopPeriod = 1 // pause in seconds
            var ix = -1
            function loopImg() {
                ix = ++ix%images.length
                let img = document.querySelector("#imgPlaceholder")
                img.src = folder + images[ix]
                setTimeout(() => { loopImg() }, 1000 * loopPeriod);
            }
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
                loopImg();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <title> Recent and Ongoing Events in the Department of Physics </title>
    <body style="background-color:powderblue;">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img id="imgPlaceholder" style="height: 300px;">
        </div>
        <h1 style="color:blue;">Department of Physics - Events and Activities</h1>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>



And btw, <center> tag is outdated, unsupported in modern browsers, so you should use text-align: center CSS attribute of parent html node instead.

Thank you for this example..very helpful. But here I have to give by hand the .jpg files. Is there a way  it pick image file name automatically from the folder?? Thanks a lot again.

There can be a couple of solutions : 1) Code server backend for URL API/Request-Images, which when requested with Javascript fetch() call- will return list of valid images. Then store this list as a slideshow array variable. 2) If images file names are structured on the server ,- for example as "file_1", "file_2", "file_3". Then you could generate file names automatically like 'prefix_'+ ++ix+'.jpg', instead of manual image list. In both solutions you should know something about server, because Javascript can't access remote or local folders structure directly - forbidden by policy.
